# Manhattan distance between point and line

Tags: geometry, geometric-measure-theory

*What is the minimum manhattan distance between a point A, with coordinates (i,j) and a point B on line y=mx+B* 
In other words: 
$$\operatorname{min}{[\operatorname{D_T}{(A,B)}]}$$
Where $B=(x,mx+b)$ and $A=(i,j)$
So far I’ve got the following:
$$\operatorname{min}{[\operatorname{D_T}{(A,B)}]}=\vert(i-x)\vert+\vert((j+b)-mx)\vert$$
Is there anyway to expand the following, I don’t understand how to make sense of opening up the absolute value.